# Does Unix grep work faster with long or short search terms?

Tags: unix, performance, speed, grep

Is it faster to look for long or short search terms? Or does it affect speed at all? In other words, should you make search terms as exact as possible?

There are more than 100 000 files and each file contains between 20 and more than 5000 rows of data. Usually the grep is used to find just one instance of the search term.

Let's say the search term is `SEARCHTERM`, and it will be in a row like this:

```
NAD+DP+1234567890:92++UNIQUE+NAME+SEARCHTERM++12345+FI'
```

Is it faster to look for "SEARCH" or "SEARCHTERM"? Let's say that in this case we don't care if we also find matches in other unrelated lines.

This is how I currently do it:

```
grep NAD+DP 123* | grep SEARCHTERM
```

But I find it quite slow, still. It usually takes around 3-5 minutes to find the data, even when I know the rough filename, which limits the range to around 10 000 files.

So, would a longer or shorter search term help? As far as I know, grep looks for "blocks" of words of a certain length?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some reference material:

> GNU grep uses the well-known Boyer-Moore algorithm, which looks first for the final letter of the target string, and uses a lookup table to tell it how far ahead it can skip in the input whenever it finds a non-matching character.

from [Why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html).

> The algorithm preprocesses the string being searched for (the pattern), but not the string being searched in (the text). [...] In general, the algorithm runs faster as the pattern length increases.

from [Boyer–Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

**Conclusion: Use longer strings**.

Now, a bit of benchmark for fun:

```
# Initialisation
cd $(mktemp -d) && dd if=/dev/urandom of=random bs=1M count=1000
# Version
grep --v` # grep (GNU grep) 2.9
# Benchmark
(for s in 'short' 'this is not so short and we could even consider this as pretty long'; do for t in {1..10}; do time grep "$s" random; done; done ) 2> result
```

Results: 0.952s is the average for the short string, 0.244s is the average for the long string.

**NB**: The length is not the only criterion to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can try yourself using SEARCH or SEARCHTERM. Also try changing the order of the two grep commands.
Anyway the only useful option will be most probably to use several CPU cores for one search. See the `parallel` command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think specifying more specific search term will make it noticeably faster.

With so many files to search, you need to somehow index your data to make search faster.

I can suggest few ways:

- Create database (PostgreSQL or MySQL), import your data into database - one file in one row, add FTS (full text search) index. Create some utility to query database.
- Import data into database in more granular way, probably one line into one row (or maybe more than one table), create indexes such that your data is searchable by using index(es). Create some utility to query database.
- Add your files into `git` repository, compact it using `git gc`, use `git grep` to search. In my experience, `git grep` can be faster than standard `grep` by factor of 10x-100x.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, a shorter term will require less CPU time, as `grep` will be doing

```
if (filechar[i] == pattern[i]) ...
```

fewer times.  In reality, I would guess that a `grep` would be I/O-bound and not CPU-bound, so it won’t matter.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this is wrong as grep is using a really smart algorithm, please refer to my answer.

Comment: the longer the search string, the more characters it can skip when it finds a mismatch, hence the search will be faster